# Improve performance of per-pixel image multiplication with mask and thresholding

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, filtering, profiling

I am looking for suggestions to make this algorithm run faster. Using C# and EmguCV (a managed wrapper over OpenCV), I am processing images in real-time, adjusting the gain of pixels that are *not* fully saturated (basically a flat-field correction with a threshold). The code works correctly, but the CPU usage is relatively high due to frame-rate and image size.

I have dabbled a bit with using UMat to perform the same operations, but performance has been worse. I also tried a version with integer math (i.e., doing integer multiplication and division instead of a FP multiply), but that was slower than leaving it in floating point.

I have profiled the code and optimized it some by doing things like reusing my Mat objects, pointing Mats to existing blocks of memory instead allocating new memory, etc. Suggestions using OpenCV would also be welcome, and I will find/use the EmguCV equivalents.

```cs
var ushortImage = new Mat(_frameH, _frameW, DepthType.Cv16U, 1, (IntPtr)pixelsPtr, _frameW * 2);

//get mask of all the pixels that are at max-value
CvInvoke.InRange(ushortImage, _lowerRange, _upperRange, _byteMask);

//convert input to float for multiplication
ushortImage.ConvertTo(_floatFrame, DepthType.Cv32F);

//multiply each pixel by it's gain value 
CvInvoke.Multiply(_floatFrame, gainMat, _floatFrame);
                
//threshold to allowable range
CvInvoke.Threshold(_floatFrame, _floatFrame, _frameMaxPixelValue, _frameMaxPixelValue, ThresholdType.Trunc);

//convert back to 16-bit
_floatFrame.ConvertTo(ushortImage, DepthType.Cv16U);

//restore the max-intensity pixels
ushortImage.SetTo(new MCvScalar(_frameMaxPixelValue), _byteMask);
```

Here is the profiling info from dotTrace. Nothing really stands out as being the bottleneck, so I'm hoping there's a way to combine some operations into a single function call. Even a 10% improvement would be helpful because I'm trying to basically double the throughout of the application.

[image]